# How many different mutually noncongruent trapeziums can be constructed using 4 distinct side lengths from the set {1, 3, 4, 5, 6}?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

How many different mutually noncongruent trapeziums can be constructed using 4 distinct side lengths from the set
{1, 3, 4, 5, 6}?

Answer (score 0):

The trick to this one is to observe that every 'congruence class' of trapeziums can be defined by their 4 side lengths and which pair is chosen as the parallel lines.

Hence there should be 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
5 \\ 2
\end{pmatrix} \cdot 
\begin{pmatrix}
4 \\ 2
\end{pmatrix}$$ possible choices.

If you were being extra thorough, you should also prove that each orientation is possible and 'unique' .